# Is PHP serialize function compatible UTF-8?

Tags: php, serialization, utf-8

I have a site I want to migrate from **ISO** to **UTF-8**.

I have a record in database indexed by the following primary key :

```
s:22:"Informations générales";
```

The problem is, now (with UTF-8), when I serialize the string, I get :

```
s:24:"Informations générales";
```

(notice the size of the string is now the number of bytes, not string length)

**So this is not compatible with non-utf8 previous records !**

Did I do something wrong ? How could I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: @Col Shrapnel: That's called 'French' and is, as such, not this strange.

Comment: He wasn't referring to the language. He's using a serialized PHP string as a primary key. That IS strange.

Comment: @Boldewyn he is probably not referring to French.

Comment: lol, you are funny. I prefer answering : I know, really, this is *strange*, but this is a very particular case, please ignore that ^^ (in fact that is not a primary key but I have a situation when I have to... you know... anyway)

Comment: Irony, there you go... However, it might be valid. Think of unique URIs, and if that is the local part (url-decoded), it's a perfectly valid reason to use it as primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is completely correct. Two strings with different encodings will generate different byte streams, thus different serialization strings.

Comment: Ok so this is normal : the process of serialization needs memory length, not string length

Comment: @Matthieu: I know this sounds strange, but in PHP strings are actually byte arrays. You will get the same output if you `echo strlen($utf8EncodedString)`. For the *character* length, you need `mb_strlen()`.

Comment: Another one: `file_get_contents()` will give you a string (even when getting contents of binary files). Socket functions, too.

Comment: Yep I know all that, its just I wanted to be sure if serialize was using "string length" or "memory size". And apparently this is memory size, so I just have to re-generate all my database records that contain serialized data (previously encoded in ISO) with PHP UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

Dump the database in latin1.

In the command line:

```
sed  -e 's/latin1/utf8/g' -i ./DBNAME.sql
```

Import the file converted to a new database in UTF-8.

Use a php script to update each field. 
Make a query, loop through each field and update the serialized string using this:

```
$str = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $str);
```

After that, I was able to use unserialize() and everything working with UTF-8.

Comment: The big problem with this is that if your string has double quotes in it they will be preceded with a backslash as PHP ineptly tries to help you (this is a side-effect of the "e" flag).  Using "preg_replace_callback" seems to be a decent way to solve this.

Comment: You are right @MichaelChaney. I had this issue recently and fixed it by using this regex pattern `/!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!/s` in preg_replace, instead of  `!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se`. Not sure whether this one got any side effects or drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

To unserialize an utf-8 encoded serialized array:

```
$array = @unserialize($arrayFromDatabase);
if ($array === false) {
  $array =  @unserialize(utf8_decode($arrayFromDatabase)); //decode first
  $array = array_map('utf8_encode', $array ); // encode the array again
}
```

Comment: I found this solution very useful when you have preexisting serialized data encoded in ISO-8859-X and need to use it in an application ported to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 4 and 5 do not have built-in Unicode support; I believe PHP 6 is starting to add more Unicode support although I'm not sure how complete that is.

Comment: I know that, I just wanted to know about the "primary key" situation

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong. PHP prior to v6 just isn't Unicode aware, and as such doesn't support it, if you don't beat it to be (i.e., via the `mbstring` extension or other means).

We here wrote our own wrapper around `serialize()` to remedy this. You could, too, move to other serialization techniques, like JSON (with `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` in PHP since 5.2.0).